# Failed to install Python packaging tools

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

при создании проекта в pycharm получаю такое сообщение:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А затем при добавлении интерпретатора, я должен скачать python packaging tools, в результате тоже получаю ошибку:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что мне делать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно установить distutils и проблема решиться

`sudo apt-get install python3-distutils`